# Failing to install the package "Pygments" with brew

Tags: homebrew, python, latex, package-management

I'm try to use the `minted` package in latex to display code in latex document. I get an error message "you must have pygmentize installed" to use this package. So I tried to install the package `Pygments` with `brew`

I typed the following line `brew install Pygments` but get the following message

```
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

By the way, the if I type `pip3 install pygments` I get 
`Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.3.1)` which means that `pip3` has installed on the machine but `homebrew` doesn't know where it is

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message says pygmentize why are you trying pygments?

Comment: thank you @Mark for your comment: because I found that the package `pygmentize` is part of.

Comment: Seems the Pygments package is not part of brew distribution, only a Python package to be installed with pip. Just be sure the execution path declared contains also the pygments path (as python path)

Comment: thank you for your comment @Yoan. This is indeed a question I have been facing many times but recurrently have trouble overcoming: so after typing `pip3 show Pygments` I get the path where that package is installed namely: `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. Moreover, when I launch python from the `Terminal` and type `import pygments` no error message is displayed. That means that it is correctly installed but that the latex editor cannot find it. Do you have an idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Use the command ```which python``` for path finding, Then in your init file add the following: ```(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Users/yoan/anaconda3/bin:"
    (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Users/yoan/anaconda3/bin")```. The path should end in a /bin folder, above is mine.

Comment: thanks a lot for for your answer @Yoan. Where can I find the init file?

Comment: @Yoan That probably is the best answer but you missed a big step **install Anaconda** and also is emacs code

Comment: as I tried to avoid mixing `pip3` and `anaconda` I didn't install anaconda on purpose...

Comment: @Mark, please do not confuse **python anaconda** with **anaconda-mode** which is emacs code, but different. First one is a python distribution, while the second one is a concurrent to elpy module (and a weird name too).

Comment: @ecjb, I use python anaconda because it can be installed to $HOME folder and removed by simply moving to trash the folder anaconda3. Another main advantage is this way it completely isolate python3 from the rest of system and I do not have to take care of pip3, python3, and so on. Just only python or pip.

Comment: @ecjb, environment and execution path example above should be modified with your actual path for python3.

Comment: thank you @Yoan. Is the init file your referring to a `.py` file? if yes. Where can I find it?

Comment: @ecjb, Oh, what editor do you use for your latex? By "init" I meant init.el in ~/.emacs.d/ if you use Emacs as your editor. If not, we will see...

Comment: @youan 1 the question says nothing about emacs why mention it?

Comment: 2 you are using the anaconda python distribution  op is not so to use your setup he needs to install anaconda. And where is anaconda mode mentioned. You are missing out assumptions you are making that are not obvious  and need to be documented. Remember the purpose is a question and answer that can be understood by others some time later.